# Can only run my copy_files.py from one directory

Tags: python, paramiko

I can run my `copy_files.py` script from only one directory.
When I run it from other directories, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./copy_py", line 36, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 56, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 27, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from asn1crypto.algos import DSASignature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asn1crypto/algos.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .core import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asn1crypto/core.py", line 53, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/xjacrawf/work/pyth/copy.py", line 106, in <module>
    cli = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
AttributeError: module 'paramiko' has no attribute 'client'
```

I have tried to remove all of the script's body, even renamed the script.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
import cx_Oracle
import glob
import os
import time
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient

cli = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
```

I expect the script to establish a connection, and it just errors.
I run the script from the first directory it ran from $MDS_SRC/ and it runs fine.
I can copy the entire script to my local directory , and it errors out.

Comment: cli = paramiko.SSHClient()

Comment: Same error. Runs fine from a different directory though - same user.

Comment: Adding to the confusion: When I run the following. import paramiko while running python3.6 manually, it executes the last command that called parakimio: as in copy.py  and indicates the error line in that script - which is not what I am running.

Comment: If you name your script something other than copy.py does it work as expected?  There's a standard library named copy.

Comment: It did modify the error: I ran the original copy_files.py and now it errors on a message I wrote in the copy.py script - but is not in the copy_files.py script.Very odd.

Comment: I made a copy of the copy.py in the $MDS_SRC directory, but it is now removed, and the scripts runs from $MDS_SRC directory,and it run from the local directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to hear it's working now.